# Почему свойство overflow-x:hidden обрезает верхний край изображения?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.

[Cсылка на упрощенную версию моей верстки на bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/Wile_E/6g090ec7/2/).

Код:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.sec1 {
  background-color: #e6dede;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.sec2 {
  background-color: #faf9f7;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.homer {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -105px;
}
.bart {
  width: 256px;
  background-image: url(http://widget.div.agency/star_img/-1492783852icon.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 256px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -45px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="sec1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="sec2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="homer"           src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/577e5d64c2a71155c59cd1bd.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per no justo tacimates, ex               vim nibh cibo convenire, unum rebum per an. Ne discere                 platonem honestatis eum, tation aeterno ad sed, at lorem               homero soleat nam. Eros graeco sea ea. At soleat singulis               persecuti mei. Nec et vide denique vulputate, falli tempor             sea te, per nulla blandit eligendi ex. Ius in omnis choro               fabellas.

            Id vis mutat ignota essent, tollit epicurei elaboraret ei               eos. Sale malorum duo cu, ex cum ridens torquatos, te sit               meis affert docendi. Pri et aeque zril causae, te usu quem             erant necessitatibus. No per quidam eruditi placerat. Usu               decore doctus audire cu, no mel oportere mediocrem                     molestiae. Sonet intellegat mei in, te eos ridens deleniti.             </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="bart"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Свойство `overflow-x:hidden` я использовал, чтобы обрезать правый край изображения с классом `bart`, которое выходило за пределы экрана и создавало горизонтальную полосу прокрутки в браузере.

Но это свойство также обрезало и верхние края двух изображений, которые должны быть наложены поверх верхней секции.

Пробовал `z-index`, устанавливал для второй секции `overflow-y:visible`, устанавливал `overflow-x:hidden` для `body` вместо `.sec2`, из-за чего были проблемы с адаптацией.

Ничего не помогло, помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Overflow` всегда обрезает контент и по вертикали и по горизонтали в случае с `hidden`. Если вы задаете `overflow-x` или `overflow-y` - вы можете управлять только полосой прокрутки, а обрезка будет всегда с обоих сторон. Чтобы избежать полосы горизонтальной прокрутки и скрыть горизонтальные выпады из верстки и чтобы не задавать такое серьезное ограничение всему `body`(т.к. нужно будет в таком случае тестировать весь сайт). Задайте это свойство обертке учитывая ваш отрицательный отступ:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sec1 {
  background-color: #e6dede;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.sec2 {
  background-color: #faf9f7;
}

.homer {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -105px;
}

.bart {
  width: 256px;
  background-image: url(http://widget.div.agency/star_img/-1492783852icon.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 256px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.sec2__wrapper {
  margin-top: -105px;
  padding-top: 105px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="sec1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class=sec2__wrapper>
    <section class="sec2">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="homer" src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/577e5d64c2a71155c59cd1bd.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per no justo tacimates, ex vim nibh cibo convenire, unum rebum per an. Ne discere platonem honestatis eum, tation aeterno ad sed, at lorem homero soleat nam. Eros graeco sea ea. At soleat singulis persecuti mei.
                Nec et vide denique vulputate, falli tempor sea te, per nulla blandit eligendi ex. Ius in omnis choro fabellas. Id vis mutat ignota essent, tollit epicurei elaboraret ei eos. Sale malorum duo cu, ex cum ridens torquatos, te sit meis affert
                docendi. Pri et aeque zril causae, te usu quem erant necessitatibus. No per quidam eruditi placerat. Usu decore doctus audire cu, no mel oportere mediocrem molestiae. Sonet intellegat mei in, te eos ridens deleniti. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <div class="bart"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!